# Hyperledger peer creation error

Tags: channel, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create a genesis block with the command:

```
peer channel create -c myc
```

following the install_instantiate.md file.

However I keep getting an error-message that there is no ordering service endpoint created. Somebody who can help me with this please?

Comment: Do you have the orderer up and running ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are working with *Fabric 1.0.0-alpha*. There 
the API has been changed so that you have to pass an orderer now.

`peer channel create -o orderer0:7050 -c mychannel`

Please have a look at the following document: 
https://fabric-rtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#create-channel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specifiy the orderer address ?

If you are using docker :

```
CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050 peer channel create -c myc
```

If it doesn't work, try the Getting Setup, or see the [Troubleshooting section](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asset_setup.html#troubleshooting)